# Extra Â Character added by .js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, currency

Using jQuery and the formatCurrency extension as below:

```
        $(function() {
            $(".currency").blur(function(){ formatCurrencyInput(this) });
        });

        function formatCurrencyInput(input) {
            if($(input).val() != '') {
                if(isNumeric($(input).val())) {
                    $(input).formatCurrency(null,{groupDigits:false,roundToDecimalPlace:2,symbol:'£'});
                    $(input).css('border-color', '');
                }
                else {
                    $(input).css('border-color', '#FFCCCC');
                }
            }
        }
```

All my text inputs with the "currency" class are converted from 45 => £45.00 for example.

The weird thing is if the formatCurrencyInput function is defined in the  section it works fine. If I externalise the function into a .js file, it returns Â£45.00 (note the Â character). I guess this is a character encoding issue, but how do I fix this?

Comment: try re-saving your code file with utf-8 encoding. Notepad++ can help.

Comment: @DmitriyNaumov won't help. To get `Â£` instead of `£`, the file must already be being saved as UTF-8; the problem is that the *browser* wrongly believes the file is Latin 1, and so interprets the byte sequence `\xc2\xa3` (a UTF-8 encoded pound sign) as two latin1 characters, `\xc2` (Â) and `\xa3` (£). The OP here needed to fix his HTTP headers when serving the file - not the content of the file itself on disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use any non-Ascii character in a JavaScript file, you should make sure that the server sends proper HTTP headers for it, identifying the character encoding. Other methods, such as a `charset` parameter in the `script` element used to refer to the file, or relying on the browser defaulting the encoding somehow (e.g., from the referring HTML document), as less reliable.

But if you have just a single non-Ascii character in a string literal, the simplest way is to escape it. The pound sign “£” U+00A3 can be escaped, inside a string literal, as `\xA3` or as `\u00A3`.

Comment: Thanks, escaping the char inside a string solved the problem. Ill check the headers and see what my server is representing the file as. Cheers! NFV

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
...
```

You could also try changing `£` to `&pound;`.

Comment: No luck with either of those solutions I'm afraid, also tried the charset attribute of the script tag with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Unexpected `Â` and `Ã` symbols before non-ASCII characters almost always mean that:

- You saved some text encoded using the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding
- You're reading that text as if it were encoded in (what is usually called) the [latin 1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

This happens because most of the non-ASCII characters you'll come across (at least if you're dealing with text written in languages whose writing is descended from the [Roman alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet), like the languages of western Europe) belong to the [Latin 1 unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) (including `£` and most accented or modified versions of English letters, like `é` and `æ`), and UTF 8 encodes all members of that block with a two-byte sequence starting with either the byte `C2` or `C3`. However, these bytes respectively represent `Â` and `Ã` in the latin 1 encoding.

A quick demonstration in the Python shell:

```
>>> b'\xc2'.decode('latin1')
'Â'
>>> '£'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc2\xa3'
>>> '£'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'Â£'
>>> 'æ'.encode('utf8')
b'\xc3\xa6'
>>> 'æ'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'Ã¦'
```

In the case of these unexpected characters showing up in your JavaScript, what must be going wrong is that you have saved your JavaScript file UTF-8-encoded but the browser thinks it is latin1-encoded and so is getting the wrong characters after decoding.

To remedy this, ensure you're correctly specifying the encoding of your JavaScript file using a HTTP header like:

```
content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add charset="UTF-8" to script tag.
**For Example**

```
<script src="myJSFile.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: Worked for me - thanks. This seems to have only started occurring after the last Chrome update (66.0.3359.139)

Answer (score -1):

```
   var poundSign = '\xA3';

   var dollars = "OK, gonna exchange $ " + dollarsToExchange + " for " + poundSign + guineas ;
```